# Calculate percentage of true bools to false

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, count

First of all, I am quite new to MySQL.

I have a table called bike_main, within this table there are two columns; one for date and one for north_bool. I am trying to calculate the percentage of true booleans to false booleans. For example, if four out of 10 rows in north_bool are set to 1 then the result would be 40%. I have tried;

```
    $northRidersQuery = 'SELECT count(north_bool) as number_of_rows FROM bike_main ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
    $northRidersResult=mysql_query($northRidersQuery);
    $northRidersDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($monthlyRidersResult);
```

and outputting it with

```
<h3><?php echo $northRidersDisplay ?></h3>
```

This does not output anything.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `array`

Comment: There's no point in using `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` on a query that just returns a single row.

Comment: FYI, `count(north_bool)` counts the number of rows where `north_bool` is not `NULL`. If it's not null, it doesn't care if it's `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNT(north_bool)` counts the number of rows where north_bool is not `NULL`. If it's not null, it doesn't care if it's `0` or `1`. If you want to count just `1` values, use `SUM(north_bool)`.

```
$northRidersQuery = 'SELECT SUM(north_bool)*100/COUNT(*) AS north_pct
                     FROM bike_main';
$northRidersResult = mysql_query($northRidersQuery);
$northRidersRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($northRidersResult);
echo "<h3>{$northRidersRow['north_pct']}%</h3>";
```

Finally, you need to use `$northRidersRow['north_pct']` to access a column in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ($northRidersDisplay = mysql_fetch_assoc($monthlyRidersResult)) {
    echo $row["number_of_rows"]; // echo column name
}
```

Comment: The column name is `number_of_rows`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something as

```
$qry = "select (x.true_tot/x.tot)*100 as perc 
        from ( select sum(north_bool=1) as true_tot, count(*) as tot from test ) x " ;
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$result_set = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<h3>'.$result_set["perc"].'</h3>';
```